# Are these NotePad++ features available in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, notepad++

I'm a NotePad++ user, new to TextMate.

There are some features that I really like in NP++ but couldn't figure out if TextMate support them.

**Double click on a variable and have all instances highlighted**
[image]

**View 2 text windows side by side**
[image]

**Drag a file onto another opened Window**

For this one, I don't know how to generate a screenshot ;-p. Basically, you can drag a file from Windows Explorer and drop it into NP++ to have it opened.

Comment: I got a response from TextMate support saying that they doubt they would ever implement the double click feature. =(

Comment: On the other hand, they plan to add a feature that would "highlight all occurrences of a search query in a document which could accomplish much the same task. This wouldn't be for 1.x but rather 2.0+."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of long time TextMate users are leaving TextMate land, actually. So, I'm not sure it's the right time to move to TextMate.

Emacs and Vim both do what you want and more. If you can afford the learning curve it's definitely worth it.

As for your question:

**View 2 text windows side by side**

You can have two or more windows for the same document. Assuming you are in a "project" right-click your file in the drawer and choose *Open "foo.ext" in New Window*. The two "views" contents are more or less in sync but doing cool things like columnar editing tends to break the syncing.

Due to how Mac OS X manages windows, the new window will probably be too large/too small and/or placed in a less than useful place. I use [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) system wide to manage my windows and in such a case have them the same size side by side.

**Double click on a variable and have all instances highlighted**

What do you use this for? Is this visual highlight or non-contiguous selection?

Type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to select the word, then <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to make the word your search term, then <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> or Edit > Find > Find in Project… It will show all instances of the search term in another window. You can then "jump" to any occurence and do whatever you want.

If you only want to jump from occurence to occurence, select the word then type <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to jump to the next occurence.

Another way is to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>, a little text field appears at the bottom of your window where you can type a word and see its first occurence selected in real time. Repeatly typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> will cycle through the occurences.

**Drag a file onto another opened Window**

You can drag & drop a file on TextMate's icon in the Dock. You can also right-click the file and choose *Open with TextMate* *or Open with…*. If you are in a "project" you can right-click and choose *Add Existing Files…*. Opening multiple files in TextMate will automatically create a "project" for you.

Comment: thank you for telling me about Vim. If that's the case, I might just learn Vim as well.

Comment: As for your question about "Double click on a variable," sometimes I just want to see where the variable instances are used within a function, or a file. For example, if we have a function that takes an `int number`, I want to see where `int number` is referenced within that function. Personally, I feel the ability to quickly see where a variable is used is quite handy.

Comment: Say if I were to learn how to use MacVim instead, do you have any recommendations for useful tutorial websites ?

Comment: @ShaChris23: MacVim is just Vim with a Mac-like UI. Almost everything you'll find on the net about Vim is going to apply to MacVim or GVim. Start by typing "$ vimtutor" in Terminal.app then go to http://www.vimcasts.org and http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/ for some great screencasts. http://www.vim.org is where you find Vim plugins. The trick is to force you to use it for gradually complex tasks. For me, at least. Be aware that Vim is VERY different from NP++, or just about anything for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

> View 2 text windows side by side

I just tried this and it doesn't seem to recognize this functionality.  the only time any sort of "add" icon came up was when I dragged the file into an open document and then released, but that resulted in adding the contents of the file into the document.

I just did a quick google search for "textmate split view" and it still doesn't seem to be supported according to some of the answers i found (one from [macromates wiki](http://wiki.macromates.com/Suggestions/GUI)).

> Double click on a variable and have all instances highlighted

This also doesn't seem to be supported. [This post](http://old.nabble.com/highlight-all-instances-under-cursor-td15231830.html) suggests using the `command + f` (find), put the word into find, then `command + g` to jump to the next instance of that word.

There are definitely some things that can be added to textmate to make it more robust.  If you are looking for something similar and are on a windows machine, you should check out [e text editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/).  I loved that editor when I was working on a windows machine - split view is supported, but not sure about the highlighting.  One thing that e also beats out textmate is the real time regular expression highlighting.